# 3d Touch iOS sharing feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 3dtouch, socialshare

I'm new to IOS development. Currently I'm working on 3d touch feature along with social sharing (like message, email, google, whatsapp, twitter, facebook). I'm using 2 separate viewcontrollers. I had implemented 3d touch in 2nd view controller and I'm presenting it from 1st viewcontroller. 3d feature works fine for me and in case of social sharing like message I had implemented the message sharing code in 2nd viewcontroller. While clicking on message sharing from first view controller the message sharing screen is not displaying and it shows ***Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!*** error  but if I implement separately in 2nd view controller the message sharing appears. Can anyone help me out regarding this.